# Reduce the height of column in small device (col-xs)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following div to display Image, Description, Content. The height of the div is fixed 416px. This is working fine. Till now in mobile device we were showing single column. As per our current requirement we would like to display three rows in mobile device.

I modified

```
<div class="categoryProduct col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" >
```

to

```
<div class="categoryProduct col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-6" > or 
<div class="categoryProduct col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4" >
```

I noticed that since the height was fixed to 416 there is lot of gap between rows when we shrink the size. How can i reset the size as per device.

Following is the div tag code

```
<div class="categoryProduct col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" >

    <div class="slides">
               <img src="src" width="222" height="296" />

    </div>

    <div class="productText" style="border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;">

            <p class="product-list-designer">Designer</p>


        <p class="product-list-title">Title</p>
        <p class="product-list-price">Text</p>


    </div>

</div>
```

Following is the css code

```
div.categoryProduct {
 background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 418px;
    padding: 5px 15px 20px;
}

div.categoryProduct div.productImage {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

div.categoryProduct div.productImage a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

I tried adding custom height nothing worked. If i try to remove height setting, the column alignment is lost and results page looks very untidy. I tried adding min-height for the div column.

I am lost with col-xs part rest all rendering is happening ok.